# I dump my Nfc Mifare classic 1k card but i can't emulate it with an android redmi note 11s phone

Tags: mifare, ndef, card

I just dump my Nfc Mifare classic 1k card and I want to emulate it with my phone (Redmi note 11S, with nfc).

As you can see, only the first sector of this card is write
[image]

I find an app name "Ndef tag emulator" for emulate card. I try to emulate with only the UID (D4ECCFCC) but it didn't work.

Have you an idea for writing this on "NDEF syntaxe", oh just khnow a better way to emulate a nfc card?

Answer (score 0):

This information may help you. The Sector 0 is the so called MAD (Mifare Application Directory) which says where the Applications are stored. Within the Sector 0 the first Block (0-15 Bytes) is the Manufactor-Code followed by byte 16 which is an CRC for the MAD and then the Information-Byte which is blocked for further development. Then the Application-Ids (AIDs) starts, where 2 Bytes represent an Application and the Sector to find the Application. By this logic your Data is stored in Sector 1 which is uncommonly not present in your picture.

[image]